# How do you use open source Puppet 5.x to deploy a three datanode cluster of Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, puppet

I want to deploy a Hadoop cluster using Puppet.  I expect to have three live nodes in the web UI.  The "Datanode Information" in the web UI shows only two nodes are live.

I am running RHEL 7.x in AWS.  I am using Puppet 5.x on the Puppet Master and five Puppet agents.  I am trying this Hadoop module: https://forge.puppet.com/cesnet/site_hadoop/

I configured this site.pp file to have three slave nodes:

```
$clients = [
  'client.example.com',
]
$master = 'master.example.com'
$slaves = [
    'node1.example.com',
    'node2.example.com',
    'node3.example.com',
]
$zookeepers = [
  $master,
]
# set to false for initial run
$hdfs_deployed = true

class { '::hadoop':
  hdfs_hostname       => $master,
  yarn_hostname       => $master,
  slaves              => $slaves,
  frontends           => $clients,
  nfs_hostnames       => $clients,
  zookeeper_hostnames => $zookeepers,
  hdfs_deployed       => $hdfs_deployed,
}

class { '::hbase':
  hdfs_hostname       => $master,
  master_hostname     => $master,
  slaves              => $slaves,
  zookeeper_hostnames => $zookeepers,
}

class { '::hive':
  metastore_hostname  => $master,
  server2_hostname    => $master,
  zookeeper_hostnames => $zookeepers,
}

class { '::spark':
  hdfs_hostname          => $master,
  historyserver_hostname => $master,
}

class { '::site_hadoop':
  users => [
    'hawking',
  ],
}

# required for hive, oozie
class { '::mysql::bindings':
  java_enable => true,
}

node 'master.example.com' {
  class { '::zookeeper':
    hostnames => $zookeepers,
  }
  include ::site_hadoop::role::master
}

node 'node1.example.com', 'node2.example.com', 'node3.example.com' {
  include ::site_hadoop::role::slave
}

node 'client.example.com' {
  include ::site_hadoop::role::frontend
}
```

I ran "sudo puppet agent -t -d" on the three slave nodes, the client node and the master node multiple times.  There was never an error.  When I log into the Hadoop web UI, I see that only two data nodes (two of the three slave nodes in the site.pp manifest) are present.  Is the third one supposed to be hidden as it is for fault tolerance?  I think it is supposed to be a live node.  Why is a live node not appearing in the cluster?